# Let $X_i$, where $i \in I$ be regular topological spaces. Show that $X=\prod_{i} X_i$ is also regular.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $X_i$, where $i \in I$ be regular topological spaces. Show that $X=\prod_{i} X_i$ is also regular.

Let $x \in X$ and $U = \prod_{i}U_i$ be a nbhd of $x$. As each $X_i$ is regular we have that $\forall i \in I$ there exists a nbhd $V_i$ of $x_i$ such that $\overline{V_i} \subset U_i$. Now by definition $\overline{V}= \prod_i \overline{V_i}$ and so $$\overline{V}= \prod_{i}\overline{V_i} \subset U = \prod_{i} U_i$$

which implies that $X$ is $T_3$ as we can find a nbhd $V$ of $x$ for which $\overline{V} \subset U$.

Is the proof correct? I'm not sure where should I state that $V$ is a nbhd of $x$ contained in $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not** by definition that $\overline{V}= \prod_i \overline{V_i}$ holds, it's a **theorem** (for both the product and the box topology BTW).

The proof you give is only valid for the *box* topology as it stands: a basic neighbourhood of $x$ is not in general of the form $\prod_i U_i$ without any qualifications. This only holds for the (rarely used) box topology.
But to make it work in a general product space we must *add* the requirement that $I':=\{i \mid U_i \neq X_i\}$ is finite. Also, better start with an arbitrary open set $O$ in the product that contains $x$ and have $x \in \prod_i U_i \subseteq O$ (with the extra requirement for the product topology), using the standard appropriate base.

After this start, use regularity in each space $X_i$ with $ i \in I'$ to get open $V_i$ with $x \in V_i \subseteq \overline{V_i} \subseteq U_i$ for all $i \in I$. Then define

$$V = \prod_i V_i \text{ with } V_i = X_i \text{ for } i \notin I'$$ which is a basic neighbourhood of $x$ (in the appropriate topology!) and apply the **theorem** on closures to conclude

$$x \in V \subseteq \overline{V} = \prod_i \overline{V_i} \subseteq \prod_i U_i \subseteq O$$ and QED. The last inclusion is obvious in either topology ($\overline{X_i}=X_i$ etc).

So be a bit more careful, though the basic idea was sound.

Comment: Thanks Henno! This makes it clear.